# Classes for background layer and parallax effect

Tags: object-oriented, objective-c, ios, graphics

I have two classes `DigBackground` and `DigParallaxBackgroundLayer` (a parallax background is a image consisting of several images that move at different scroll speeds, for games etc.).  My idea was to have the `DigBackground` class which is basically just a image with some added properties that can be set were it will draw itself on the screen. It just has one method currently and that is the `initWithImageNamed` that sets all of it properties.  Some of its properties are public, but read-only. So they can be accessed by the `DigParallaxBackground` class.

The `DigParallaxBackground` class currently also have one method at present - the initializer which takes an array of `DigBackground`´s as argument. And will display them on screen.

I want to know if this is decent design and how I can improve it if need be.

This is how it's used:

```
    DigBackground *bg1 = [[DigBackground alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"Default.png"
                                                  withScrollSpeed:1.0f
                                                  InitialOffsetOf:ccp(0, 0)
                                                         position:ccp(100, 100)
                                                         setFlipX:NO];




    DigParallaxBackgroundLayer *parallaxBg = [[DigParallaxBackgroundLayer alloc]
                                              initParallaxBackgroundWithImages:@[bg1] inOrder:kAscending];


    [self addChild: parallaxBg];
```

Header for `DigBackground`:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) float bgScrollSpeed;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGPoint initialOffset;


// Designated initializer
- (id) initWithImageNamed: (NSString *)image
          withScrollSpeed: (float)scrollspeed
          InitialOffsetOf: (CGPoint)offset
                 position: (CGPoint)position
                 setFlipX: (BOOL)flipX;
```

Header for `DigParallaxBackground`:

```
typedef enum {
    kAscending,
    kDescending
} ImagesOrder;

@interface DigParallaxBackgroundLayer : CCLayer
{
    NSArray *backgrounds; 
}


// Designated initializer
- (id) initParallaxBackgroundWithImages: (NSArray *) images inOrder: (ImagesOrder) order;
```

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward. `InitialOffsetOf:` is not idiomatic, I would have expected lowercase, and why not just `initialOffset:`? Also, are there technical reasons why the properties should be immutable once set? I would think that especially in games, being able to vary the scroll speed is an advantage if implementing that is straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

Just a couple nit-picky things...

`InitialOffsetOf:` should instead be `initialOffset:`

`withScrollSpeed:` should just be `scrollSpeed:`

I'd probably also add factory methods.  When I'm writing code, no class is complete until it has its factory methods.